# c thread program that ends with user input valgrind problem

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, valgrind

So i wrote a simple c program the idea was that it would print out a message and whait for the user to give a message and if the message was "izhod" it would end the program. It works fine but i get a valgrind
error.
This is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

   void* wait(void* arg){
     while (1){
    printf("cakam...\n");
    usleep(1000*1000);
}//while
return NULL;
}//wait

int main(int argc, char **argv){
pthread_t id;
bool running = true;
char messageLen[10];
pthread_create(&id, NULL, wait, NULL);
while (running){
    scanf("%s", messageLen);
    if (strcmp(messageLen, "izhod") == 0){
        running = false;
    }//if
    printf("Sporocilo: %s\n", messageLen);

 }//while
return 0;

}//main
```

[image: This is the error:]

I tried to add pthread_join and pthread_exit but that puts it in a infinite loop. Any help would be great so thank you.

Comment: As noted in the link, this is an implementation issue and not a real memory leak.

Comment: ok don't know how i missed this